# Eclipse external tool for Qt .ui to .py with pyuic

Tags: python, eclipse, qt, pydev

I use PyDev in Eclipse with the Qt integration. With an external tool I can create python source in a .py from a qt .ui file. This is the external tool:
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.xy.devel/413
The problem is that the generated python .py file has a name like MyGeneratedFile.ui.py. 
How can I adapt the external tool to have the extension of the generated file without .ui thus MyGeneratedFile.py ?

Answer (score 10):

So it seems the problem boils down to **${resource_loc}**, since this gives you the full path name **/path/to/file/filename.ui**  - Yes, it does include the **.ui** hence when you say **${resource_loc}.py** this translates into **/path/to/file/filename.ui.py**

So probably the simplest way to correct this problem since I couldn't find a way to make eclipse remove the file extension for me was making a very small script to do work.

You might need to modify it slightly to work for your pyuic installation.

**/usr/bin/pyuicEclipse:**

```
#!/bin/bash
pyUICCommand="/usr/bin/pyuic" # change this per your installation
x=$1
f=`basename $x`
d=`dirname $x`
fNoUI="`echo $f | sed 's/\.ui$//'`" # removes .ui extension from file basename
$pyUICCommand -o ${d}/${fNoUI}.py $x
```

make it executable and the eclipse configuration I used was much simpler:

- PyUIC->Main->Location: */usr/bin/pyuicEclipse* **---obviously change this to yours**
- PyUIC->Main->Arguments: **${resource_loc}**
- PyUIC->Refresh - check *"Refresh Resources upon Completion"*
- PyUIC->Build - uncheck *"Build before Launch"*
- PyUIC->Common - don't do the File option that was mentioned in that article

This works on linux, so if you're on another OS it may need some slight modification, but I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: Hmmm... I was worried it would require a script. Not that I mind using one, but it just seems a little bit of a hack for an otherwise well-featured IDE.

Comment: You could always [request a variable feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F) from eclipse developers that outputs the filename without the extension. But that may take a while if it ever gets implemented. Worth your time probably in the long run.  -- The final option would be to modify the pyuic source code and make it automatically remove any .ui extensions that may be there - I don't recommend this since upgrades will leave you having to re-apply this patch every time.

Answer (score 5):

In the interests of maintaining the cross-platform nature of Eclipse, I've knocked up a DOS equivalent of platinummonkey's bash script. It's not quite so robust, but it does the job:

```
@echo off
set pyUICCommand="pyuic"
set fname=%1
set fname=%fname:.ui=.py%
%pyUICCommand% -o %fname% %1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy solution to this problem that requires no scripting at all.

1. Install [pathtools](http://code.google.com/p/pathtools/) plugin either through Eclipse updates or via the [Eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/):
2. Setup an External Tools Configurations option in Eclipse as follows

In Main:

1. Name: pyuic_run. (or something similar)
2. Location: path to the python interpreter (or pyside-uic.exe if you use this)
3. Arguments: On the first line, put the path to pyuic.py (not needed if you use pyside-uic.exe as it will be above). Use double quotes around the path if it contains spaces. On the second line put "${resource_loc}" (this will set the name of the resource file)
4. In refresh: Enable "Refresh resources upon completion" (to see the final file)
5. In Build: Disable "Build before launch" #not necessary here
6. In Environment: No changes
7. In Common: Activate the "File" option and set the path to be:
   ${parent-path}/${name-sans-extension}.py

Note that ${parent-path} and ${name-sans-extension} are arguments made available through the pathtools plugin.

If you apply this and then run the configuration on a .ui resource file, you'll see a new .py file created.