# Running pyside-uic before every run inside Eclipse

Tags: python, pyside

Kinda of a trivial problem: I'm building an Pyside application using QtDesigner and Eclipse Pydev. Is there any automated way of running pyside-uic before every test run inside Pydev/Eclipse? So I don't have to go to the terminal, or keep bashing my head against the wall trying to find out why the code is not working :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a builder to automatically create the .py files from the .ui files.

Have you taken a look at the following question: [Eclipse external tool for Qt .ui to .py with pyuic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541024/eclipse-external-tool-for-qt-ui-to-py-with-pyuic) (I think it should solve your problem).