# How can I use argument only file name on Eclipse External Tools?

Tags: eclipse, batch-file

I make batch file to use with Eclipse External tool.

I refer this site: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm

In this site, Variable Example "${resource_name}",it's results is "MyFile.txt"

I want to use arguments like "MyFile", What can I do like this?

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

This is the plugin you might be looking for
https://github.com/basti1302/startexplorer

eclipse plugin called "path tools" seems promising as well
Check this link as well..
[Eclipse external tool for Qt .ui to .py with pyuic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541024/eclipse-external-tool-for-qt-ui-to-py-with-pyuic)