# Recovery of Qt4 Designer Integration with PyDev for Eclipse neon.2

Tags: eclipse, pydev

My Eclipse Neon.2 crashed recently and now the integration of PyQt, in particular the integration with Qt4 Designer seems to have become corrupted. It was the case that I could open a *.ui file from Neon.2 to Qt Designer, make some changes & then run (from Neon.2) a *.py file which accesses the variables created in Qt4D. Now python fails on any new variables I add in Qt4D, but is ok with those created before the crash. I suspect the PyDev integration in my Neon.2 has been corrupted such that the auto pyuic4 does not get run. Question. How do I get out of this mess, eg re-install PyDev in Eclipse (or some other way perhaps)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, PyDev didn't actually do anything automatic in this regard (i.e.: by default it doesn't translate .ui files to .py files with pyiuc4).

The way to do that automatically would be creating a custom builder (**right click a project > properties > builders > new > program**) and then configure it to run some program which would check if it was a .ui file changed and call pyuic4 on it.

[Eclipse external tool for Qt .ui to .py with pyuic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541024/eclipse-external-tool-for-qt-ui-to-py-with-pyuic) has something you could probably use.

Not sure how it worked before for you though... maybe some co-worker had it configured for you or your project already had those settings saved?

Answer (score 0):

Well this does what I wanted:

```
qtcreator_file  = "test1.ui" # Enter file here.
Ui_Dialog, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtcreator_file)
```

My guess is it basically runs something like pyuic4 this avoiding running ones self after having made changes is QtDesigner.